# An iPhone app in Spanish which requires a windows software to work

Tags: iphone, internationalization

I have just finished my first iphone app and I'm almost ready to submit it for review, however I have some questions:

1- My app is in Spanish only.

Can I submit applications in Spanish only?

Is there anything special I have to do in order to accomplish this?

2- My app is a wi-fi remote controller for a PC-only software. If I run the iphone app without the other program running on the PC or if there is no network communication between the two then all I get is a UIAlertView with some help and a retry button.

How is Apple going to review my app? They can’t see it working unless they install and run the Windows program. Do I have to provide Apple with the Windows program as well?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Leave detailed reviewer notes. Be prepared to ship the PC only software to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spanish only definitely isn't a problem.

There may be a problem with the software - Maybe before you submit it, change that UIAlertView to a modal view controller which explains more about the software where you get it etc.

If it is paid for software then you may well have to supply it to the app review team.

Answer (score 0):

1)Yes, your app may be Spanish only

2)I believe there will be no problem at all